# how to write regular expression to identify lines of the tabular format in a text file?

Tags: regex, scala

While iterating over each line I need to find this table in a text file some where in the middle. What regular expression is appropriate to identify that we are reading tabular data like the one shown below.

```
     TABLE

NAME OF ISSUER                 TITLE OF CLASS   USID     (x$1000)  PRN AMT PRN CALL DSCRETN MANAGERS         SOLE   SHARED     NONE
------------------------------ ---------------- --------- -------- -------- --- ---- ------- ------------ -------- -------- --------
ABC INC                    COM              00P65A10N    42336  3150000 SH       SOLE                  3150000        0        0
ACC INC                    COM NEW          00D09F70Z    22095 10294886 SH       SOLE                 10294886        0        0
ABC DEF CORP               SHS              A11209100     2708  1037690 SH       SOLE                  1037690        0        0
```

Comment: Can you post what you have tried until now?

Comment: Yes, do show what you've tried and then give us a bit more of a clue about what is in the rest of the file, whether you know what the column headings will be, whether that word "TABLE" is actually part of the data, and so on

Comment: ".*([A-Z0-9]{9})\\s+(([0-9]+)\\s+)+(\\w+\\s*){2}(([0-9]+)\\s*){3}" , that worked for me temporarliy, but I dont know if thats the robust solution. Regarding the table, the whole format is as mentioned in the above comment, which appears somewhere in the text file. Unfortunately I can disclose much info about the files.

Comment: Then there's pretty much no way we can help. You know the file format, and what else it contains. We don't